# AngularJS: How to get controller in directive to access value in view?

Tags: angularjs

So, I'm using a directive which is a form to allow the app user to edit or create users.
When I navigate to users/:id, I'm pulling in a userDetail view which pulls in a directive user-form.

```
...
<h1>User Detail</h1>
<p>{{ detail.first_name }}</p>
<p>{{ userDetail.last_name }}</p>
<p>{{ userDetail.age }}</p>
<p>{{ userDetail.address }}</p>
<p>{{ userDetail.gender }}</p>

<user-form ctrl="editUser" user-detail="userDetail"></user-form>
```

- This view has a controller which pulls in the userDetail via an ajax call:

```
userDetail.controller("UserDetailController", ['$http', '$scope', '$routeParams', function($http, $scope, $routeParams) {
    function getUser() {
        var url = "http://localhost:3000/api/users/" + String($routeParams.id) 

        $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
            $scope.userDetail = response.data;

            if (!response.data) {
                document.location = '/#!/error'
            } 
        })
    }

    getUser();
}]);
```

So I created my directive and its controller is based on the **ctrl** attribute when I pull in the directive depending on the page I am:

```
function createUser($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
    $scope.submitUser = function(isValid) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/users'
    var data = $scope.user;
    var config = 'contenttype';

    if (isValid) {
      $http.post(url, data, config).then(function(response) {
        $scope.users.push(response.data);  
      });
    }
  }
}

function editUser($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //get $scope.userDetail
        //assign $scope.user = $scopeDetail to populate the form with the details to allow editing. 
        console.log($scope.user);
    }, 2000)
}

function userFormDirective() {
    return {
        scope: { users: '=', userDetail: '=', user: '='  },
        name: 'ctrl',
        controller: '@',
        templateUrl: 'components/userForm/userForm-template.html',
    }
}
```

```
var app = angular.module('user-management', [
  'ngRoute',
  'users',
  // 'userForm',
  'userDetail'
]).directive('userForm', userFormDirective)
    .controller('createUser', createUser)
    .controller('editUser', editUser);
```

Here is my userForm template:

```
<form name="userForm" novalidate ng-submit="submitUser(userForm.$valid)">
    <fieldset>
        <dl> 
            <dt><label for="first-name">First Name</label></dt>
            <dd><input id="first-name" ng-model="user.first" type="text" required /></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl> 
            <dt><label for="last-name">Last Name</label></dt>
            <dd><input id="last-name" ng-model="user.last_name" type="text" required/></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl> 
...
```

So basically, when I go to users/2, it does an AJAX request to get the user details 9Hence, a timeout function). Then, I want the directive's controller to access the models in the view so that I can assign the userDetails that were obtained and assign it to the models in the view, thereby autpopulating it and allowing edits. Not sure if this is a correct way of doing it because I'm rather new to AngularJS.

Comment: Instead of `setTimeout`, use the [$timeout service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) which is integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: I think you need to separate some of what you're doing, your <user-form> is accepting a list of users, a user, and a userDetail (which presumably are the same).  You should probably have a `<user-list>` which is /users and then a `<user-details>` which is /users/2 and then a `<user-form user="user">` where `$ctrl.saveUser` comes from `userDetails` controller and does either a POST or PUT based on whether user.id exists (or whatever your rules are).  You shouldn't need a `setTimeout` or `$timeout` to get the user as long as the directive has an `=` scope.